# Token authentication (instead of PAT token) to Azure DevOps REST API via Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to use the Azure DevOps Rest API in an `Azure DevOps Pipeline`. I know it's possible to connect through a PAT token, but there should be a way to use service principal to connect to Azure?

What do I have to change to obtain a bearer token when I run below's code in an `Azure DevOps Pipeline`?

```
  Connect-AzAccount -WarningAction 'SilentlyContinue' | Out-Null
  $Token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798").Token # Resource url is for Azure DevOps REST API source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69996528/authenticate-azure-devops-api-call-without-using-a-pat
  $AzureDevOpsAuthenticationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $Token }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops) Currently, it is not possible.
**Azure DevOps API doesn't support non-interactive service access via service principals.**

There is **no access** control of **service principal in Azure DevOps**.

#### Non- interactive ways follows

- [**PAT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) (Most Recommended way)
- [**Azure AD ROPC flow**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) (Not recommended because while request we have **expose the username and password**)

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68480267/15997690) for more information